# Using awk to modify output

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a command that is giving me the output:

```
/home/konnor/md5sums:ea66574ff0daad6d0406f67e4571ee08  counted-file.xml.20131003-083611
```

I need the output to be:

```
ea66574ff0daad6d0406f67e4571ee08  counted-file.xml
```

The closest I got was:

```
$ echo /home/konnor/md5sums:ea66574ff0daad6d0406f67e4571ee08  counted-file.xml.20131003-083611 | awk '{ printf "%s", $1 }; END { printf "\n" }'

/home/konnor/md5sums:ea66574ff0daad6d0406f67e4571ee08
```

I'm not familiar with awk but I believe this is the command I want to use, any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or just a sed oneliner:

```
 echo /home/konnor/md5sums:ea66574ff0daad6d0406f67e4571ee08  counted-file.xml.20131003-083611 \
     | sed -E 's/.*:(.*\.xml).*/\1/'
```

Comment: It still needs to drop the trailing `.20131003-083611` from the file name. Simple change... `'s/.*:(.*\.xml).*$/\1/'`

Comment: Oopsie... forgot about that :)

Comment: bro... this is the most beautiful thing I've ever seen. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo "/home/konnor/md5sums:ea66574ff0daad6d0406f67e4571ee08  counted-file.xml.20131003-083611" |
  cut -d: -f2 |
  cut -d. -f1-2
ea66574ff0daad6d0406f67e4571ee08  counted-file.xml
```

Note that this relies on the dot `.` being present as in `counted-file.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this is ok for you:

```
sed 's/^.*:\(.*\)\.[^.]*$/\1/'
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "/home/konnor/md5sums:ea66574ff0daad6d0406f67e4571ee08  counted-file.xml.20131003-083611"|sed 's/^.*:\(.*\)\.[^.]*$/\1/'                                        
ea66574ff0daad6d0406f67e4571ee08  counted-file.xml
```

this **grep** line works too:

```
grep -Po ':\K.*(?=\..*?$)'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F[:.] -v OFS="." '{print $2,$3}' <<< "/home/konnor/md5sums:ea66574ff0daad6d0406f67e4571ee08 counted-file.xml.20131003-083611"
ea66574ff0daad6d0406f67e4571ee08 counted-file.xml
```